# Material Ui, MUI, Dialog, ScrollTop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I was messing around alot with scrollTop and the Dialog component(**A fullscreen fixed modal**) from Material-Ui for some time... and I couldn't quite get **scrollTop** to work. **When i click the go down button, It would always give me undefined or it wouldn't work at all in the scrollable container**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed was needed

**Make sure the div within the Dialog has overflow**

```
<Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <div ref={ref}  
//MOST IMPORTANT
 style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', overflowY: 'auto', height: '100%' }}>
```

**And an onClick **

```
<Button
autoFocus
color="inherit"
//HERE
onClick={() => {
const div = ref.current;
div.scrollTop = 800;
}}
>GO DOWN
</Button>
```

Here's an example
https://codesandbox.io/s/fullscreendialog-material-demo-forked-cf8u6?file=/demo.js:2201-2434